# Meaning of "Forgetfulness in"

Tags: meaning

What does "forgetfulness in" mean?

> So he closed his eyes and let himself feel, that last time, **forgetfulness in** Meggie.

I read it in ["The Thorn Birds"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1Uw-AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT576&lpg=PT576&dq=forgetfulness%20in%20Meggie&source=bl&ots=KBOLLR2jWJ&sig=ACfU3U25qDSHbAiFR-MZoFuwNS2_6DpHHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR7vePp5n2AhUYk4kEHRtRAtQQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=forgetfulness%20in%20Meggie&f=false)

Comment: Please look up the word and show the definition before asking us. Thanks.

Comment: What does the meaning of " forgetfulness in" mean? Does it mean that he felt that Meggie was forgetting him?

Comment: Please read this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm leaving this open, as the question is about an uncommon phrasing, and the only source for answers are other Q&A websites, which are no more authoritative than this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special meaning, but that doesn't mean this is easy to understand.

Forgetfulness has its normal literal meaning, the property of being forgetful.

> Forgetfulness is a problem that many older people have.

And "in Meggie" is a prepositional phrase telling us where that forgetfulness is, or rather who is forgetful.

But it isn't clear how you can "feel forgetfulness in someone".  This is poetic language, and the meaning is not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I think it may mean that he felt forgetfulness in hug of Meggie. Is it true?

Comment: Perhaps.  Was he hugging Meggie at the time?  I still don't understand what the interpretation of this poetic phrase is.  And on ELL, I don't try to do [literature.se] analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting example of some metaphorical/figurative language. It shouldn't be taken literally. To understand what it means, you must look at the context, in this case, the whole paragraph, and also the beginning of the next chapter.

It's a rather touching death scene. The feeling of "forgetfulness in Meggie" is the moment of Cardinal (Ralph) de Bricassart's death, in Meggie's arms. This is made abundantly clear in the first line of the next chapter.

> He [Cardinal Ralph de Bricassart] was hardly conscious of the pain, intent only on
> Meggie's arms around him, the way his head sank against her. But he
> managed to turn until he could see her eyes, and looked at her. He
> tried to say, Forgive me, and saw she had forgiven him long ago. She
> knew she had got the best of it. Then he wanted to say something so
> perfect she would be eternally consoled, and realized that wasn't
> necessary, either. Whatever she was, she could bear anything.
> *Anything!* So he closed his eyes and let himself feel, that last time,
> forgetfulness in Meggie.
>
> Chapter 19
>
> Sitting at his Bonn desk with an early-morning cup of coffee, Rainer
> learned of Cardinal de Bricassart's death from the newspaper.